# Pass List To View C# Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ESSEntities DB = new ESSEntities();
    List<EmployeeMdl> EmpList = DB.Employees.ToList();

    return View(EmpList);
}
```

How do I pass this list to view because I got error

> Cannot implicitly convert type '' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Can you show your `View` also?

Comment: Try this `var EmpList = DB.Employees.ToList();`

Comment: @Aravind - that won't change a thing...

Comment: You have to convert Employees objects to EmployeeMdl before passing it to view.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ESSEntities DB = new ESSEntities();
    List<Employees> lstDBEmployees = DB.Employees.ToList();

List<EmployeeMdl> EmpList = new List<EmployeeMdl>();
foreach(var thisEmployee in lstDBEmployees )
{
       EmpList.Add(new EmployeeMdl(){
           prop1 = thisEmployee.prop1,
           prop2 = thisEmployee.prop2
       });
}
    return View(EmpList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is not receiving List please use this.

View:

```
@model List<EmployeeMdl>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
//code here
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
ESSEntities DB = new ESSEntities();
List<EmployeeMdl> EmpList = DB.Employees.ToList();

return View(EmpList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var EmpList = 
DB.Employees.Select(c => new{ /*your model properties somthing like c.EmployeeId, c.EmployeeName*/}).ToList();
```

Try this.